# How to enable usb debugging on bootloop phone(Lenovo tab yoga 8)?

Tags: adb, usb-debugging, lenovo-yoga

So... I am having a a hard time to pull my file from internal memory on my bootlooped Lenovo tab Yoga 8. I only know that to pull files from adb I need to enable usb debugging. But, because it is stuck in the boot logo I can't go to setting to enable this. Is there anyway to enable usb debug?
And I also doesn't have any of ClockWordMod nor TWRP Recovery, I only have acces to default recovery mode and fastboot.

Right, I also has tried to install driver from device manager on Windows 10 but I can't even see device which corespond to Lenovo Yoga tab 8 or anything like that, which is also needed to do to pull files from adb, or so if I'm not mistaken.

please help!